# Find and Replace in Wordpress Title

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to do a find and replace in the title of my wordpress posts on the homepage.

Ex. 
**Title**: Free ***Song Name*** Download 
**Desired Output:** Song Name

How can i do a find and replace to remove "Download" and "Free"

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

Comment: Why are you doing a find-and-replace? If you don't want the words there, why are they there?

Comment: I want them on the post page and in other areas, just no the homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

if (is_front_page()) { 

    $title = str_ireplace(array("Download","Free"),array(""),get_the_title());
    echo "<h2>".$title."</h2>";

} else {

?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: str_ireplace would be perfect and array("") is enough instead of array("","").

Comment: This did not work; i tried and copied exactly but nothing changed.

Comment: Which file are you putting this in?

Comment: I adding it to my main index template

Comment: I edited the code above.  I changed `is_home` to `is_front_page`.  It should work now.

Comment: What is the exact filename you're putting this in.  I tested with a fresh WP install and it behaved well

Comment: Shadows: Main Index Template (index.php)
The name of the template is shadows.

Comment: I put the code in line #13 in `index.php` in the Shadow theme, replacing `<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>` with the code in my answer and it works.  I'm running WP 3.2.1

Comment: I don't have that line of code on my shadow theme. I am also running WP 3.2.1; maybe i have an outdated version of the shadow theme.

Comment: As long as you put it in the same location as your other `the_title` statement then it should be fine.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/content/88/8768688/html/whatisrapmusic/wp-content/themes/shadows/index.php on line 38

Comment: If you put that inside of a `<?php` make sure you don't have it twice, like `<?php        <?php`

Comment: <a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="opacity"><?php the_post_thumbnail('shadows-featured-image'); ?> 
        <h2>

<?php the_title(); ?>

</h2>

Comment: Replace `<h2> <?php the_title(); ?> </h2>` with the code in the answer.

Comment: No idea why its not working, but that is what i have been updating. I just tried again and the original title is still showing. Everything is spelled correct and has the same Uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: try just putting this in `$title = str_ireplace(array("Download","Free"),array(""),get_the_title());
    echo "<h2>".$title."</h2>";`